# batch file to set wireless hotspot on system boot

Tags: batch-file, startup, autorun, netsh

Good Evening all,

I would like to write a batch file to run the following commands on boot

1) First of all create a 60 second delay before executing the following command 
then
2) netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=WLAN_XXXX key=XXXXXXXXXXX
3) Delay of 10 seconds
4) netsh wlan start hostednetwork

thankyou for your help.

Simon

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Hi Nweg, I have no idea how to write batch, I was looking for a little help here, to guide me in the right direction, maybe there is a better way to approach the requirements. Thankyou for replying.

Answer (score 6):

Since you tagged "autorun", I'll assume this is a windows system.

a [startup script](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770556.aspx) could look something like:

```
timeout 60
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=WLAN_XXXX key=XXXXXXXXXXX
timeout 10
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

On windows systems without the availability of the timeout command, you could use ping for the delays as ping waits 1 second between sending packets:

```
ping -n 61 127.0.0.1 > nul
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=WLAN_XXXX key=XXXXXXXXXXX
ping -n 11 127.0.0.1 > nul
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

The relevant part from linked article about creating startup scripts:

> To assign computer startup scripts
>
> Open the Local Group Policy Editor.
>
> In the console tree, click Scripts (Startup/Shutdown) . The path is Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Scripts (Startup/Shutdown).
>
> In the results pane, double-click Startup.
>
> In the Startup Properties dialog box, click Add .
>
> In the Add a Script dialog box, do the following:
>   In the Script Name box, type the path to the script, or click Browse to search for the script file in the Netlogon shared folder on the domain controller.
>
> In the Script Parameters box, type any parameters that you want, the same way as you would type them on the command line. For example, if your script includes parameters called //logo (display banner) and //I (interactive mode), type //logo //I.
>
> In the Startup Properties dialog box, specify the options that you want:
>   Startup Scripts for  : Lists all the scripts that currently are assigned to the selected Group Policy
>   object (GPO). If you assign multiple scripts, the scripts are
>   processed in the order that you specify. To move a script up in the
>   list, click it and then click Up . To move a script down in the list,
>   click it and then click Down .
>
> Add : Opens the Add a Script dialog box, where you can specify any additional scripts to use.
>
> Edit : Opens the Edit Script dialog box, where you can modify script information, such as name and parameters.
>
> Remove : Removes the selected script from the Startup Scripts list.
>
> Show Files : Displays the script files that are stored in the selected GPO.

**Edit:**

Easier explanation about startup scripts from [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/116120/need-a-way-to-run-a-script-on-windows-boot-up-prior-to-a-user-logging-in):

> You can use a Group Policy (or the local policy) to assign a startup
>   script; you can configure it in the section *Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Scripts (Startup/Shutdown)*.
>
> You can also use Scheduled Tasks to configure a task to run at
>   computer startup.

Comment: brilliant, Ill get onto that first thing, Id like to keep you updated of progress if that sounds ok..